# Space between GroundOverlays using Google Map Android API v2

Tags: openstreetmap, android-maps-v2

I have created an off-line map with Google Map Android API v2 (i.e. osmdroid is not an option) using Openstreetmap tiles as GroundOverlays with one minor problem: at zoom level greater than 14 some of the tiles have a 1-3 pixel space between them. Other tiles line up perfectly. It seems random which ones do and do not have spaces between them.

I download the tiles using JTileDownloader, then I fetch the required tiles (using the technique described [here)](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) that I downloaded and placed in the device filesystem, then I get the tiles' LatLngBounds, and then I lay them down in a loop as:

```
groundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mBitmapImage))
                    .positionFromBounds(tileBoundsArray[i])
                    .transparency((float)0));
```

I have verified that the lat and long of the tiles should line up. I also verified that all the bitmaps are the same size. I have also tried this particular tileset using the UrlTileProvider and it works fine, so it's nothing wrong with the tiles.  I have been struggling with this for days and would appreciate any suggestions. I have found absolutely nothing anywhere else addressing this issue. Thanks!

Comment: any reason you are using groundoverlay instead of a tileprovider?

Comment: that's ultimately what I did - switched to tileprovider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this.  I had to specify the width of the map tile in meters at the tile's latitude (I used the center of the tile). Google maps uses a Mercator projection, which means that the width of the map depends upon the latitude.  You specifiy the width using GoundOverlay.setDimensions(width).  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa940990.aspx) page gives an explanation on how to calculate the width.